How do I reach Mips in the Uncanny Courtyard in the B3313 Romhack?
I am trying to collect all of the stars in the Super Mario 64 romhack B3313 v1.0.  My issue is that two of the stars are dropped by Mips in a hole high above the the castle entrance in the Uncanny Courtyard.  I don't know how to reach this hole.
Side flipping from the ledge above the door won't get me high enough.  I am unable to wall jump from the ledge.  And launching myself off the top of a nearby tree hasn't worked either due to the awkward angle.
Any suggestions?

You can reach MIPS in Uncanny Courtyard using side flips. However, you'll need to collect at least 1 red star in order to increase the height of your side flip and 15 stars overall for him to appear.



Additional notes:

If you have no red stars, you can collect your first one by going through the center upstairs doors in the lobby, entering the trapdoor, and fighting Bowser.
Collecting at least 1 red star enables various effects such as higher side flips, enabling long jumping, and opening doors in the Castle Grounds outside of the front doors.
MIPS appears twice in Uncanny Courtyard. Once when you have 15 stars and again when you have 50.
Prior to v1.0 Hotfix 2, MIPS would also appear in Crimson Hallway and Wing Cap by the Rainbow Highway

